# Inserting data into database using gridview at runtime

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a grid view with two columns. One named **Reg_No** and the other named **Marks** (Marks columns in template field with TextBox in ItemTemplate).

The Reg_No column is bound to the "College" table and it displays the reg_nos from database thro sql datasource.

I need to insert the values into the same database table "College" through textbox in grid view, but I am not sure how to do this.
Here is my code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WCCConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [Reg_No] FROM [College] " >


    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Height="283px" Width="343px" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reg_No" HeaderText="Reg_No" 
                SortExpression="Reg_No" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

<br />
```

Comment: Bad, bad, bad. Throw away all that SqlDataSource stuff. Going from web page directly to DB is a bad practice. It was used by MS folks on conferences to show how they can do stuff with few clicks and how simple it all is. But in reality this is good only for demos and "mickey mouse" apps.

Comment: Actually am new to this sql datasource... I just tried it with grid view coz i could retrieve data easily. So can u suggest me anyothr way to do the same process plz..

Comment: Programming is not about dragging and dropping from toolbox in visual Studio. You'll have to work and learn. But usually we separate accessing database from displaying data. In that way I could have same code for both desktop app and web app. You can do it with DataReader/DataWriter or by using something like NHibernate for accessing MySql. You'll read data into POCO (google it, basically simple objects with string, int etc. properties). You end up with list of these POCOs. Then you build a web page from them.

Comment: So you separated stuff. No you can split work in 2 parts. For example, for building the web page you can create these POCOs (Employee, Product, Person) manually or from flat file. You don't need database to work on web page side of things.

Comment: Fine.. Initially my teacher wanted us to retrieve reg_no of students into labels and also provide a textbox for each student and get their marks inserted into database at the click of a button. But i learnt this way of accessing database in a similar website oly..I used this as it was easier.. Now can u help me with the code plzz...